# Error when parse json object in java with Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a json string like this:

```
String result={[{"id":"2","fullname":"Course 1"},{"id":"3","fullname":"Course 2"}]}
```

In java I wrote this code to decode that json string:

```
public class Courses {
public String id,name;  
}
Gson gs = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Courses>>(){}.getType();
List<Courses> listCourses= gs.fromJson(result, listType);
```

But I always receive error:

> 06-09 04:21:11.614: E/AndroidRuntime(449): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.

What am I wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you json string `Result is not valid`.[see here](http://jsonlint.com/) valid or not

and it should be

`[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "fullname": "Course 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "fullname": "Course 2"
    }
]`

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

   JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   int id = objJson.getInt("id");
   String fullName = objJson.getString("fullname");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your json is not valid one..please check with some jsonvalidator whether the json is in correct format. To check the json Format refer the link

[JSONFormat](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

To get the string from json, refer the below link as

[AndroidJson](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)

[Parsing Json](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

I think it may helpful to you..